# avoid cytoscape js from resetting layout after adding an edge

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am adding an edge on clicking a dialog button.
It is a pretty large graph.
I zoom to a particular node, then add the edge through the dialog.
The edge gets added, but the layout goes back to fitting within the entire view.
How do I ensure the zoom level does not change after the edge is added and the new edge is visible?

On more observation, I see that the layout resets as soon as the dialog opens.

```
const handleAddEdge = () => {
    let edge = {
      data: {
        source: tfSrcNodeValue,
        target: tfTgtNodeValue,
        label: tfEdgeLabel,
      },
    };
    let g = graphData;
    g.edges.push(edge);
    setGraphData(g);
    setOpen(false);
  };
```

Comment: The layout algorithm should have "fit" option. You need to set it to false to prevent fitting to entire window.